# Generate random plot for slope

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to generate a set of random plots like this one: [image: this]; where I randomly generate the equation (in this case, y =2x + 3) and then draw an empty plot for students to plot the points for that equation.

I wrote this code, that generates the equation, and tells me what dimensions the plot should be:

```
start_pos_number = random.randint(1,5)
start_neg_number = start_pos_number * -1
eq_connector = ['+','-']
equation_x_y = random.sample(range(1, 5), 2)
eq = 'y = ' + str(equation_x_y[0]) + 'x' + str(random.choice(eq_connector)) + str(equation_x_y[1])
x = range(start_neg_number,start_pos_number)
pos_y = equation_x_y[0]*start_pos_number + equation_x_y[1]
neg_y = equation_x_y[0]*start_neg_number + equation_x_y[1]
y_range = range(neg_y,pos_y)
print(eq)
print(x)
print(y_range)
```

I was then trying to plot the data:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.spines['left'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
plt.plot()
plt.show()
```

Which gives me:[image]

I can see there are multiple issues with this. Can someone tell how to change this code to:
1. Actually draw the line (like in the example) as there is no line drawn in my attempt.
2. make the numbers/limits of the x and y axis match the numbers generated in the first part of the code (or more generally, how do I just put in two random ranges, an x range and a y range, and change the plot accordingly.

Comment: You never apply any limits to the subplot, therefore it defaults to 0-1

Comment: The line is white in your case (you see that its above the labels); and the reason is that you are using a style sheet that turns the spines white. Use the default style and your lines will be black as expected.